# All pairs shortest path algorithm logic with single matrix

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I am reading about All pair shortest path algorithm in Data structures and Algorithm analysis by Wessis book

> As shown in below pseudo C code, when k > 0 we can write a simple
>   formula for Dk,i,j. The shortest path from vi to vj that uses only v1,
>   v2, . . . ,vk as intermediates is the shortest path that either does
>   not use vk as an intermediate at all, or consists of the merging of
>   the two paths vi vk and vk  vj, each of which uses only the first k -
>   1 vertices as intermediates. This leads to the formula
>
> Dk,i,j = min{Dk - 1,i,j, Dk - 1,i,k + Dk - 1,k,j}
>
> The time requirement is once again O(|V|3). Because the kth stage
>   depends only on the  (k - 1)st stage, it appears that only two |V| X
>   |V| matrices need to be maintained. However, using k as an
>   intermediate vertex on a path that starts or finishes with k does not
>   improve the result unless there is a negative cycle. Thus, only one
>   matrix is necessary, because Dk-1,i,k = Dk,i,k and Dk-1,k,j = Dk,k,j,
>   which implies that none of the terms on the right change values and
>   need to be saved.

My questions:

1. What does author mean by "However, using k as an intermediate vertex on a path that starts or finishes with k does not improve the result unless
   there is a negative cycle" ?
2. How author concluded that "Dk-1,i,k = Dk,i,k and Dk-1,k,j = Dk,k,j"?

Can any one pls explain with simple example

```
/* Compute All-Shortest Paths */

/* A[] contains the adjacency matrix */

/* with A[i][i] presumed to be zero */

/* D[] contains the values of shortest path */

/* |V | is the number of vertices */

/* A negative cycle exists iff */

/* d[i][j] is set to a negative value at line 9 */

/* Actual Path can be computed via another procedure using path */

/* All arrays are indexed starting at 0 */



void

all_pairs( two_d_array A, two_d_array D, two_d_array path )

{

int i, j, k;



/*1*/        for( i = 0; i < |V |; i++ ) /* Initialize D and path */

/*2*/               for( j = 0; j < |V |; j++ )

{

/*3*/                  D[i][j] = A[i][j];

/*4*/                  path[i][j] = NOT_A_VERTEX;

}

/*5*/        for( k = 0; k < |v |; k++ )

/* Consider each vertex as an intermediate */

/*6*/        for( i = 0; i < |V |; i++ )

/*7*/                  for( j = 0; j < |V |; j++ )

/*8*/                       if( d[i][k] + d[k][j] < d[i][j] )

/*update min */

{

/*9*/                            d[i][j] = d[i][k] + d[k][j];

/*10*/                           path[i][j] = k;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the answers to your questions.

1) The Floyd algorithm exploits a dynamic programming recurrence equation to determine all-pairs shortest paths among vertices; the recurrence is based on the fact that, in order to find a shortest path between a couple of vertices *i* and *j* you must check if going directly from *i* to *j* is cheaper than going from *i* to an intermediate vertex *k*, and then from *k* to *j*. You check this for all vertices *i*, *j* and *k*, so that the complexity is O(*n*^3). Now consider this: if all of the weights are non-negative, then the notion of a shortest path is well defined. Instead, if there are negative cycles, this notion is meaningless. Why? Because if you find a negative cycle on the path from a vertex *i* to a vertex *j*, then you can traverse the cycle as many times as you wish, and each time you traverse the cycle, the cost of the corresponding path decreases because the weights on the edges belonging to the cycle are negative. So, a negative cycle obviously improves the cost of a shortest path (the cost decreases). Therefore, it is important to be able to detect negative cycles if you allow negative weights on the edges. The Floyd algorithm assumes edges are positive, but is able to detect a negative cycle.

2) The recurrence equation is the following, slightly simplified with regard to your notation:

```
d[i, j] <- min(d[i, j], d[i, k] + d[k, j])
```

this is actually used as shown in the following pseudocode

```
for k <- 0 to n-1
   for i<- 0 to n-1
      for j <- 0 to n-1
         d[i, j] <- min(d[i, j], d[i, k] + d[k, j])
```

Each update of d[i, j] requires accessing d[i, k] and d[k, j], so the author is asking: if updating  d[i, j] requires the values d[i, k] and d[k, j] how can we be sure that those values have already been computed during the *k*-th iteration ? How can we be sure that those values do not change during the *k*-th iteration?

Actually those values cannot change during the *k*-th iteration, so that there is no functional dependence. Here is why. Indeed, during iteration *k*, the update to d[i, k] takes the form

```
d[i, k] <- min(d[i, k], d[i, k] + d[k, k])
```

but d[k, k] is zero, so that d[i, k] does not change.

Similarly, the update for d[k, j] is

```
d[k, j] <- min(d[k, j], d[k, k] + d[k, j])
```

so that d[k, j] does not change too.

Comment: @venkysmarty: if you liked the answer you should upvote/accept it. If you did not like it, then you should downvote it and explain why. Please act accordingly, otherwise people will not answer your questions. Time is a scarce and precious resource for all of us. Thank you.